# TFS 2018 macros

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

on my queries to see the work items of my current iteration I use the @CurrentIteration macro. Does anyone know if you can create new macros on TFS 2018. I would like to be able to query the items of the previous and future release something like

- Previous Sprint: `@CurrentIteration - 1`
- Next Sprint: `@CurrentIteration + 1`

Comment: There's a TFS 2018? Why wouldn't you use Git?

Comment: The short answer is: No macros are hardcoded and can't be added/removed by users or admins.

Comment: @MitchWheat this has nothing to do with [tag:git] vs [tag:tfvc], it's entirely workitem related.

Comment: @ jessehouwing: well, yes I know that. But having used both, IMO you'd be mad to stick with TFS. Many dev teams have swapped or are swapping....Just checked you're Bio and you're a Microsoft MVP in the area of ALM, so you opinion is hardly unbiased!

Answer (score 2):

"@CurrentIteration" does not support this operations. But UserVoice contains your request: [VSO Support @currentIteration+-1 for next or past iteration](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/13314216-vso-support-currentiteration-1-for-next-or-past).

Waiting for answer from developer team.....